# JS/Jquery Export to pdf scrolling div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, export

Is it possible to export the contents of the scrollable div which contents table, content & graphs created using highchart to PDF. Also want the styling to remain intact.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

Comment: @santi yes. I  want a plugin or code that can do this.

Comment: http://www.cloudformatter.com supports highcharts and such and you can use a scrollable div

Comment: @kevin. But its uses http://xep.cloudformatter.com/Chandra.svc/ within js so it seems to be some third party. Is it feasible to use? If its server it down then there will be issue right?